# How to add limits on inputs of multiple integers?

Tags: variables, if-statement, integer

I want to add a limit on all variables >=40 and <=100. If the input matches with both conditions, then the program will execute. Otherwise it will show invalid.. how should I do it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, avg;
    printf("\n Enter your Subject Numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &s1, &s2, &s3, &s4, &s5);

    avg = (s1+s2+s3+s4+s5)/5;
    if (avg>=80)
    {
        printf("\n Your Grade is : A+");
    }
    else if (avg>=70)
    {
        printf("\n Your Grade is : A ");
    }
    else if (avg>=60)
    {   
        printf("\n Your Grade is : A- ");
    }
    else if (avg>=50)
    {
        printf("\n Your Grade is : B ");
    }
    else if (avg>=40)
    {
        printf("\n Your Grade is : C ");
    }
    else if (avg<40)
    {
        printf("\n Your Grade is : F ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit. Somebody downvoted it, probably because it is a  rather elementary question. When asking on Stack Overflow, it helps if you show what you've tried. Using the following basic format can help you: "I tried ..., I expected ...., but what happened was ...". The more effort you show here, the more positive people will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. You need an extra `if` statement *around* your code:

```
if (avg >= 40 && avg <= 100 )
{
    /* Your code here */
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid input.");
}
```

There are a few other ways, like putting a separate `if (avg >= 100)` at the top and an extra `else` at the bottom. But then you'd have to repeat the code that prints "Invalid input". While that is not a problem in a very small program like this, it becomes ugly in bigger programs.

Note that your case may not be `avg <= 40`. That case now prints "Your Grade is : F". You probably meant to have "Invalid input" for the situation where `avg` is below 0.
In fact, it's better to check each input separately *before* calculating the average.

You may also want to learn about the `switch` statement in C. It will provide you with a more concise alternative to this long list of `if` statements.
But for now, I suggest you focus on validating your inputs.